# Using 110-220v charger to charge laptop battery which says 14.8 v

Tags: conversion, adapter, charger

I am sorry if this seems a silly question but I am worried about ruining my laptop.
The battery of my laptop no longer worked. It was 14.6 V /2670 mAh. I had been charging this with 220v plug socket without any problems.
I bought a new battery which is 14.8 v/ 2600 mAh. Now I am worried whether this would cause a problem. 
Also, the charger I use says Input: 100-240 V ~1.5A, 50/60 Hz. Output: 19.5 V 3.33 A.
Can you please tell me if I can use this new battery without having to buy an adaptor?
Thank you

Comment: The *actual* charger is built into your notebook. Your *power supply unit* voltage is not related to the battery voltage.

Answer (score 0):

That small of a voltage difference won't cause any harm and as long as you're using the same adapter the laptop came with than you have nothing to worry about. The mAh rating determines how long the battery's charge will last.

[How to buy a laptop battery](http://www.batteryeducation.com/2010/05/how-to-buy-a-laptop-battery.html)

[Power adapter compatibility](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/choose-right-power-adapter-charger-phone-laptop/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to look not the battery voltage but the input voltage of your laptop. If the trafo (that's how the "converter" is called) is the original to the product, you don't have to worry about that.
Sadly I have no time to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

The power adapter that you plug into the wall converts your household AC voltage to the DC voltage the laptop needs.  That adapter needs to handle the utility power in your country.  It's common for those adapters to be sold for use all over the world, where voltage standards vary.  So a label that says 100-240V means that your country's 220V is in the range it can handle.  Any utility voltage in that 100-240 range will produce the labeled output voltage for the laptop.

The battery's mAh rating reflects how much energy it is able to store, which translates to how long you can operate the laptop before it runs out of juice.  A higher mAh rating means you will be able to operate longer before needing to recharge.  The new battery's 2600 mAh vs. the original 2670 is a difference of a few percent, which translates to a few minutes difference in run time.

The 14.6 V vs. 14.8 V on the battery is immaterial.  The batteries have the same chemistry, or they wouldn't work right with the charging circuit.  The chemistry defines the voltage.  When they are fully charged and under no load, they have a slightly higher voltage, which quickly drops to a nominal voltage when you start using it.  Different manufacturers sometimes pick different characteristic voltage points to label the battery.  Maybe it's marketing (a higher voltage sounds like you're getting something better, right?).  That difference of a few tenths of a volt is just a labeling choice; the actual battery voltages are the same.

To charge a battery, you need a source voltage that is higher.  The values that are used range up or down a few volts, but that 19.5 V value matches what your specific laptop expects to work with.  So if you ever need to replace that adapter, you would want another with the same output voltage.

Assuming that adapter is the original that came with the laptop, its 3.33 A capacity was sized to the laptop's needs.  If you ever need to replace it, you will want one with at least the same capacity.  The laptop only pulls what it needs when it needs it.  That rating reflects the maximum current the laptop can draw without burning out the adapter.

The battery charging circuitry is actually in the laptop.  The adapter is just the source of power.  The charger regulates the power going to the battery.  As long as you replace the battery with another designed for your laptop, it will be fine.  If you were to replace it with a high capacity battery, it would take a little longer to charge.

So bottom line, your new battery should be fine, and you don't need to change anything else.